# Console.log using react - it returns Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

Tags: reactjs

i am new to react and have some difficulties using console.log.

I would like to log inside this element for example:

```
{!!image && (
      <div className={styles.media}>
        <DisplayImage 
          className={styles.imageWrap}
          id={image}
          alt={imageMeta?.altText}
          imageMeta={imageMeta}
          nextImageFill={true}
          {console.log()} // like this 
        />
        {console.log(DisplayImage)}
        {console.log(imageMeta.mediaItemUrl)}
      </div>
    )}
```

It returns Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "..."
How should i do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `debugger` instead...

Just before your `return` statement, throw a debugger in, make sure you are looking at the cycle where all your information is loaded. Remove the `console.log()` statement inside of your `DisplayImage` component, you are treating that like a custom prop being sent through and it will not work that way.

Once you are in the debugger, you can check all your state, props, values etc inside your dev console on your browser or IDE.

Comment: Ah ok perfect. Yes what i thought. I thought perhaps there is another way to insert a console.log in the props section... Well, thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

In React there is a pattern when you can destructure an object's properties, and pass them as props to a Component, using `...` that is used for **object destructuring**, for example:

```
const object={prop1:someValue,prop2:someValue2}

return <Component
       {...object}
        />
```

Now, `prop1` and `prop2` of `object` will be passed to `Component` as props.

In your situation, when you use `{ }` in `<DisplayImage/>`, React thinks you want to do the same thing, but you don't use `...`, which leads to an error.

**In Other words, you can't use `{ }` for any other reason than object destructuring when rendering a Component.**

Anyway, There is no point in logging something there. You can do that in the body of the Component

```
const Component=()=>{
   console.log(something)
   return (<div>....
```